# C++ geting error while using function inside class

Tags: c++, class, function, header, void

I can't figure out why I get this error: "the function was not declared". I am still a newbie at programming, but I am trying my best to learn it!
so here is my code, I would be realy greatful if you could help me:
main:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include "szovegkezelo.h"
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string sz;

    beolvas(sz);
    kiir(sz);


    return 0;
}
```

header:

```
#ifndef SZOVEGKEZELO_H_INCLUDED
#define SZOVEGKEZELO_H_INCLUDED

#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class szovegkezelo {
protected:
    string sz;

public:szovegkezelo
    void beolvas(string &sz);
    void kiir(string t);


};

#endif // SZOVEGKEZELO_H_INCLUDED
```

cpp:

```
#include "szovegkezelo.h"
#include <iostream>

void szovegkezelo::beolvas(string &sz)
{

    getline(cin, sz);

}
void szovegkezelo::kiir(string t)
{
     cout << "a beadott szoveg: " << t << endl;
     cout << "a string hossza: " << t.size() << endl;
}
```

Comment: Do not use `using namespace std`, qualify the names where they are used to avoid confusion

Comment: 1. Which line is the error on? 2. What's `public:szovegkezelo`, a constructor with missing parts? I'm guessing your problem is due to not creating an object of your class before using the functions, but that shouldn't be all.

Comment: 1. These are the errors I get:

nd\Downloads\HULRAAI(2)\ZH\main.cpp|10|error: 'beolvas' was not declared in this scope|

2. I was experimenting and left it there, sorry for that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Your `two or more data types...` error comes from a misuse of...something...after that public access specifier.

  Change this:

  ```
  public:szovegkezelo
  ```

  to this:

  ```
  public:
  ```

  If you're trying to make a constructor, it needs to be declared like any other function, minus the return type.

---

- Your other error occurs because this function was declared improperly.

---

- Other than that, you need to create an object before you can call the class's functions. Each object has it's own set of variables that the functions work on. I would seriously recommend reading a good beginner C++ OOP book.

  Somewhere in main, you need to create an object:

  ```
  szovegkezelo myObject;
  ```

  Then, use it to call functions:

  ```
  myObject.kiir (sz);
  ```

---

- Finally, note that your data members should typically be declared with the `private` access specifier. `protected` has nothing to do with normal classes that are not inherited from.

Comment: This fixed it! Thank you a lot! I have been trying to get this work for almost 2 houres and now its finaly working :D
many many thanks!

Answer (score 3):

From what it looks like, you are trying to call a classes function (method) called 'beolvas' from 'main' but because it belongs to a class, you can't call it like that, you need to create an instance of that class and call the method on that instance, or make the function static and call it from the class.

Your first option is to create an instance of the class and then call the methods on the class like so:

```
int main()
{
    string sz;
    szovegkezelo szov;

    szov.beolvas(sz);
    svoz.kiir(sz);

    return 0;
}
```

Your second option is to make the functions in your class static, this way they will not need an instance of the class to be called:

```
int main()
{
    string sz;

    szov::beolvas(sz);
    svoz::kiir(sz);

    return 0;
}

static void szovegkezelo::beolvas(string &sz)
{

    getline(cin, sz);

}
static void szovegkezelo::kiir(string t)
{
     cout << "a beadott szoveg: " << t << endl;
     cout << "a string hossza: " << t.size() << endl;
}
```

Been a while since I've done anything static in c++ so please correct me if I've done something wrong in the second option.

Comment: and could you explayin how do I do that please? As I mentioned before I am begginner at programming and try to experiment with new things

Comment: @user1402297, I provided an example, but you should really go through some kind of chapter in a book. It will give you all the things you need to know.

Comment: thank you a lot :) I belive the best way to learn is trough exercise with tasks.

Comment: @user1402297, that's one thing a book is good for. At the end of a chapter it should give a good number of various tasks to do so that you can practice each aspect.

Comment: Editted my post with some code to help you understand, but as chris said, try reading up more about OOP if you're going to use classes.

Comment: I can't thank you enough! :D
You realy saved me a lots of time!

Comment: @RoneRackal, for your assurance, your use of static is just fine.

Comment: @chris Thanks, it's just been a while :P

Answer (score 2):

couple of things :

1) In main you have not instantiated an object of `szovegkezelo` and you are trying to call `beolvas` . Compiler is looking for a free function `beolvas` whereas you have declared `beolvas` as member function

2) `public:szovegkezelo` is not right if you are looking for a default constrcutor that does nothing don't have that line  else if you need to do something specific with default construct declare  it as  `szovegkezelo()` in header.

3) as mentioned in comments it is not a good practice to put 
   `using namespace std` in header files or any `using namespace`

Comment: 1) This is my question, how can I fix that
2) It is 4:15 AM in my country, and I was studying the whole night, I am getting tired and left it there accidentalz while I was experimenting
3) All the tutorials I watched told me to do it that way, but thank you for the advice :)